# Undefined options for dropdown

Tags: jquery

I am getting an error that options is undefined.  The dropdown shows up but for some reason options is not accessible

dropdown.options is undefined
[Break On This Error] dropdown.options.length = ObjectCount(equtypeList);

```
$(dropdown).show(); // this works

if (ObjectCount(equipmentTypeList) > 1) 
{
    $(dropdown).attr("disabled", false); //this works
    dropdown.options.length = ObjectCount(equipmentTypeList);  //bombs out here saying options is null...wtf??
    AddDropdownOption("-- Select Equipment Type--", "-1", dropdown.id);
}
```

So I don't get it.  If I reshow a dropdow, then why is the option attribute not accessible (not usable cause it's null).  Clearly it's there as I can see the dropdown reappear on the page...but has no option attribute?  That just doesn't seem right that I would get null for the options attribute.  If it's enabled and reappears, then it's a valid dropdown and I should be able to add stuff to it agani.

Comment: What is `dropdown`? Is it a variable you defined before?

Comment: var ddlEquipType = $('#<%=ddlEquipType.ClientID %>');

Comment: I've had this working before...I'm simply specifying the length of the options array before I start adding values to it.  This was working fine before...before I started to hide and show this dropdown.  When I was just showing it and disabling/enabling it worked fine.  It's only now when I've started to hide and show this..do I get problems with no ability to set that options array length.

Comment: Just curious. Can you show where do you define `dropdown`? What happens when you inspect it in console?

Comment: solved.  I had tried to change out the js way of setting my variables to hold a pointer to my dom elements.  For example document.getElementById(...).  But then tried to change it to get the ref of the web control via jquery and must not be doing this right:  var ddlModel = $('#<%=ddlModel.ClientID %>');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `dropdown` is a jQuery object, obtained through a call to `$()`. jQuery objects do not expose an `options` property, the underlying DOM elements do.

You can use indexing syntax or the [get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method to obtain the DOM element:

```
dropdown[0].options.length = ObjectCount(equipmentTypeList);
// or
dropdown.get(0).options.length = ObjectCount(equipmentTypeList);
```

You could also build another jQuery object containing the options:

```
$("option", dropdown).length = ObjectCount(equipmentTypeList);
// or
dropdown.find("option").length = ObjectCount(equipmentTypeList);
```

However, assigning to the `length` property of a jQuery object doesn't have any effect on the DOM, so this approach probably won't give the results you're expecting.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up.  Makes sense now...just did not know that a jQuery pointer to an object is no longer the real object?  Meaning if I'm pointing to a dropdown control shouldn't I still be dealing with that web control?

Comment: when I use getElementByID to get the pointer to the dropdown and set it to my variable, my code works fine.  I don't understand why jQuery would matter.  I'd just be using the jQuery way...same way to get the item even though I'd be using the $() way wouldn't I?

Comment: jQuery objects are more wrappers than pointers. jQuery doesn't augment DOM elements like other toolkits do, but provides methods applicable to wrapped elements instead. To select an element by id and get that element, you would do something like `$("#id")[0]`.

Comment: and on top of my questions here if it's a jquery object now (and not a pointer to the dropdown), then what other than length could I use?

Comment: Well, I would avoid assigning to `length` in the first place, instead doing something like `dropdown.find("option").gt(ObjectCount(equipmentTypeList) - 1).remove();`